# Which is the Best Tool for Creating XSL File?

Tags: xml, xslt

> Which is the Best Tool for Creating  XSLT File.

Comment: Please do not shout like ..????

Comment: [dejavu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840258/which-tool-is-the-best-for-creation-of-complex-xml-transformations).

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a brief overview of six IDEs/tools for XSLT programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*XSLT IDEs* (Interactive Development Environments):

- **[XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator)** (the one I've been using for 6-7 years). Free, has a Debugger for MSXML, has intellisense for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. In addition has some dynamic intellisense. The debugger has breakpoints, data breakpoints,visualizes temporary trees, variables, test conditions, current output, ..., etc.
- **[VS2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/default.mspx)** -- a good XML Editor + XSLT Debugger. Good static intellisence. Match patterns are statically checked. Breakpoints, data breakpoints, visualization of variables and the current output.
- **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)**
- **[XML-SPY](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) (Altova)**
- **[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)**

*XPath tools*:

- **The [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV-Zip-2008.zip)** -- A [**popular tool for learning XPath**](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) by playing with XPath expressions. Free and open source. Allows any XPath expression to be evaluated against a given XML document and displayes the results hi-lighted in the xml document (if they are node(s)) or in a separate box (if the results are atomic values). Allows xsl:variable-s to be defined and then used in XPath expressions. Allows xsl:key-s to be defined and then referenced by key() functions within XPath expressions.

**EDIT**: The XPath Visualizer now has a **[new, safer home](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**, due to the kindness of Lars Huttar.

Answer (score 2):

There are loads out there. Since its just text then notepad would do just fine. [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has nicer formating and is open source. [Visual studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us) also has lovely formatting for xml and is free to download (basic versions only)

Comment: Visual Studio also supports debugging XSLT - version 1.0 only

Answer (score 0):

We use and love [Altova XML Editor](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) not expensive, nice UI and powerful.

Comment: hahaha not expensive? licenses start at $499.